# Showing article header outside container with background image

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a specific layout using Bootstrap 5 and attempt to render a tag outside his original container, taking the full page width.
I tried using absolute position on the img tag, however, doing this, footer is going over the tag which is not expected.

More than words, this is what I trying to do

[image: header img outside container]

The ideal DOM structure would be as follow :

```
<article>
  <header>
    <div>
      <img />
      <h3 />
    </div>
    <div class="meta" />
  </header>
  <div class="content" />
  <footer />
</article>
```

- img should get full x-width
- img should stay in the overal y position (meaning nothing coming after it - should go over it, like a page footer or anything else)
- h3 should be over the img tag

any idea would get a warm welcome, I'm trying to make that small thing working since over a week now :')

---

you're right

my current best attempt it this, so I split the overall structure in three distinct container box, which sounds like a bit hacky to me - and I have issues when it's rendered on mobile (ie: title is going outside down the box, instead staying stick to the bottom of the image)

```
<body class="position-relative">
    <div class="container-fluid container-lg">
        <header class="mt-5">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mt-5 mb-3"></nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    <main class="mt-5 mb-3" role="main">
        <section>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <div class="go-article-banner d-flex position-relative">
                        <img style="object-fit: cover;position: absolute;height: 300px;left: 0;right: 0;/*! width: 200%; */" class="w-100" src="...">
                        <div class="container-fluid container-lg position-relative">
                            <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 start-0 right-0" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
                                <h3 class="display-3 p-4">The War of the Worthies: the spectre of Cardan’s aggression</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <div class="container-fluid container-lg"></div>
                <footer class="container-fluid container-lg"></footer>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main>
    <div class="container-fluid container-lg">
            <footer>
                <div class="go-streaming-news d-none d-sm-block mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex justify-content-between text-uppercase" style="background-color: var(--bs-primary); padding: .5rem 1rem;">
                            <span>Breaking News</span>
                            <span style="border-right: solid 2px rgb(50, 67, 100)"></span>
                            <span>21:03</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 marquee-wrapper">
                            <div class="marquee"><div style="width: 100000px; animation: 9.64667s linear 0s infinite normal none running marqueeAnimation-39418180; transform: translateX(1084px);" class="js-marquee-wrapper"><div class="js-marquee" style="margin-right: 0px; float: left;">
                                <ul class="list-inline m-0 p-0">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">Some news</li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">Another news</li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item">Yet Another news</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, the render is good https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUBIf.jpg

My previous attempt was that one, and with that, the marquee box is going inside the article banner. This, and the title is going outside the image which is rendered using a after anchor.

```
<body class="position-relative customize-support">
    <div class="container-fluid container-lg">
        <header class="mt-5">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mt-5 mb-3"></nav>
        </header>
        <main class="mt-5 mb-3" role="main">
            <section>
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <div class="go-article-banner"></div>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <h3 class="display-3">Change of course for Eskari Industries</h3>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div></div>
                    <footer></footer>
                </article>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="go-streaming-news d-none d-sm-block mb-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex justify-content-between text-uppercase" style="background-color: var(--bs-primary); padding: .5rem 1rem;">
                        <span>Breaking News</span>
                        <span style="border-right: solid 2px rgb(50, 67, 100)"></span>
                        <span>21:03</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 marquee-wrapper">
                        <div class="marquee">
                            <div style="width: 100000px; animation: 9.64667s linear 0s infinite normal none running marqueeAnimation-33044180; transform: translateX(1084px);" class="js-marquee-wrapper">
                                <div class="js-marquee" style="margin-right: 0px; float: left;">
                                    <ul class="list-inline m-0 p-0">
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">Some news</li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">Another news</li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">Yet Another news</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

/*
Theme Name:  Galaxy One
Theme URI: https://galaxyone.news
Author: Loic Leuilliot
Author URI: https://github.com/warlof
Description: Galaxy One Gazette default template
Tags: newspaper, rising constellation, game, news
Version: 0.1
Requires at least: 5.0
Tested up to 5.4
Requires PHP: 7.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or Later
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/Licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: galaxyone
 */

@font-face {
    font-family: "Gtek Technology";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Gtek Technology.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: calc(1.375rem + 3vw);
    font-family: "Gtek Technology", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 4px var(--bs-primary);
}

.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: .7rem 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--bs-primary);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--bs-primary);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
    color: var(--bs-primary);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: var(--bs-primary);
}

.go-news .card-img-top {
    height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0;
}

.go-news .stretched-link:hover::after {
    background: #282c34dd url("./assets/img/plus-circle.svg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.go-category-link {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.go-category-link.category-sport {
    background-color: var(--bs-primary);
}

.go-category-link.category-politics {
    background-color: var(--bs-danger);
}

.go-category-link.category-financial, .go-category-link.category-people {
    background-color: var(--bs-warning);
}

.go-category-link.category-miscellaneous {
    background-color: var(--bs-success);
}

.go-category-link.category-sciences {
    background-color: var(--bs-secondary);
}

.page-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.page-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.page-item:first-child .page-link {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.page-item:last-child .page-link {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.page-item.disabled .page-link {
    background-color: var(--bs-primary);
    border-color: var(--bs-primary);
    color: #fff;
}

.page-link {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: var(--bs-primary);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.55);
}

.page-link:hover {
    color: var(--bs-primary);
}

.page-link.dots:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: var(--bs-primary);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.55);
    cursor: default;
}

.go-article-banner {
    height: 300px;
}

.go-article-banner::after {
    background: #333 url('...') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.go-streaming-news .marquee-wrapper {
    background-color: #4472c455;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.go-streaming-news .marquee {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.go-streaming-news .marquee .list-inline-item {
    border-right: solid 3px var(--bs-primary);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.go-streaming-news .marquee .list-inline-item:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: What have u tried ? a snippet will be great with what u have tried

Comment: you're right, I've updated original post with a bit of details of last 2 attempts

Comment: so how do you  want to look your final render ? sorry ! I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I wouuld get black part inside the container, but starting and ending outisde on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figure a way to do it properly (I think so at least).
Overall reference is this blog post https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

I'm using the very last alternative as detailed by "No calc() needed" which is probably the more flexible solution.

First, here is the global DOM structure

```html
<div class="container-fluid container-lg">
    <header>
        <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <article>
        <header>
            <div class="go-article-header">
                <div class="go-article-banner" style="background-image: url('...');"></div>
                <div class="go-article-title-wrapper">
                    <h3 class="display-3 m-0">Article title</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="go-article-content">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </article>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

- We have a unique container which is covering the overall page
- Inside this container, there are a global header and footer with navigation inside the header
- Between both, we have an article, container its own header and footer
- The header is containing a few wrapper for extra styling (like background under title, and so on) - I also switched from img tag to a background in order to be able to use cover property. But here again, it's much more a design choice

Now, the styling :

```css
.go-article-header {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.go-article-banner {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
    background-image: url("assets/img/eskari.png");
    background-color: #333;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.go-article-title-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Everything is happening with the `.go-article-banner` class which is first aligning the tag (using the left and right properties) and then make it start outside the box (using the margin properties). Last but not least, the width property using view width metric is ensuring the tag will use the full screen width.

Regarding title, we just need to fix it left/right/down using parent container. This is done with the `.go-article-title-wrapper` class.

Here is the final render [image]